# ¿Por que el menú no se ve bien en la versión movíl?

Tags: bootstrap, menú, responsive

**Un increíble saludo, espero estén muy bien.**

Tengo este menú lo estoy haciendo en Boostrap 3, a simple vista se ve bien, pero cuando reducimos el menú a una resolución más pequeña se desacomoda, no se ve bien, como pueden ver en la imagen, ¿no se que más puedo hacer?

**Gracias.**

[Así es el resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsXLR.png)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/*MENU*/

.navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #1A1A1A;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap
      padding: .10rem 1rem;

  }

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #B3B3B3 !important;
  }

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #FFF !important;
      background-color: #ED1E79 !important;
  }

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
      margin: 0px;
  }
 
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;
    height: 35px; /* aqui escoges el alto que necesites */
    

}

.navbar {
    min-height:32px !important; /* aqui escoges el alto que necesites */
}
```

```html
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<title>Inicio</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--HEADER-->

<header>
  <div class="container">
  <a href="index.html">
  <img class="center-block logo" src="imagenes/Logo.png" alt="inicio">
  </a>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- MENU -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>

  </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a></li>
      <li><a href="servicios.html">SERVICIOS</a></li> 
      <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</nav> 


**
```

Comment: podrias mostrar todo el documento HTML ?

Comment: Hola =) Como estas? Mira este es mi código completo. Por que tengo el header que es el logo y debajo el menú.